# Some questions related to IPv6

Tags: webserver, ipv6

I am studying a simple web server using c, and came up with some of these questions. How does IPv6 used in TCP? To use IPv6, do we have to use some form of modified version of TCP?? If we have to used the modified version of TCP, what do we have to change?? I think I read about Little Endian, as well as Big Endian, but I am not sure if there should be some special cases for IPv6.

Comment: Some of these questions can be answered on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Answer (score 2):

As you'll probably be wanting the more gory details of the API changes, it's here: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2553.html

Mostly it's a couple of longer address structures to pass in that can take a longer number and a new Family and Protocol name specified so the API can destiguish which struct you are using. Byte ordering is the same.

The actual TCP SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK stuff and all that is identical, it is literally a different IP layer frame with a longet number and other changes.

Comment: I don't know whether winsock is implementing the same changes, they usually do to resemble some form of compatibility between UNIX and Windows sockets.